# <a href> can't send data

Tags: php, html

I'm going to send data to other pages with  but it does not work as I expected.

Here is my form's code:

```
<td style="font-size:14px">
   <?php echo "<a href=\"detail_survei.php?ID_SURVEI=1\"><input name='Detail2' type='button' value='Detail'/></a>"?>
</td>
```

And the result right now after I've clicked the button, no data is being shown.

```
<?php $ID_SURVEI = $_POST['ID_SURVEI']; 
    echo $ID_SURVEI ;
?>
```

The output seems to be BLANK.

Comment: yes, because `ID_SURVEI` is `$_GET` variable, not `$_POST` in your script.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your value in `$_GET` variable use

`$_GET['ID_SURVEI']` instead of `$_POST['ID_SURVEI']`

Answer (score 1):

You want to access ID_SURVEI using $_POST which is not accessible.Use $_GET.

```
<?php $ID_SURVEI = $_GET['ID_SURVEI']; 
    echo $ID_SURVEI ;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using GET method to send the data to the server and trying to receivev it using the POST method.

you have to receive it by using the $_GET array as

```
<?php 
   $ID_SURVEI = $_GET['ID_SURVEI']; 
   echo $ID_SURVEI ;
?>
```

You are also missing a semi-column at the end of your php statement here

```
<?php echo "<a href=\"detail_survei.php?ID_SURVEI=1\"><input name='Detail2' type='button' value='Detail'/></a>"?>
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

For proper readability:

```
<td style="font-size:14px"><?php echo "<a href='detail_survei.php?ID_SURVEI=1'><input name='Detail2' type='button' value='Detail'/></a>"; ?></td>
```

Then in your PHP, you can get your value back either through $_GET request or $_REQUEST.
This is because the method for sending your data to server is GET and not POST. Also, "$_REQUEST" works for both the $_GET and $_POST method...

```
<?php 
$ID_SURVEI = $_GET['ID_SURVEI']; 
echo $ID_SURVEI ;
?>
```

or

```
<?php 
   $ID_SURVEI = $_REQUEST['ID_SURVEI']; 
   echo $ID_SURVEI ;
?>
```